# AWS Athena: "HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing column 'X' : empty String"

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

I want to create an external table on AWS Athena based on a CSV file, using OpenCSVSerde.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table`(name string, value double, group string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",", "escapeChar" = "\\","skip.header.line.count"="1",  "serialization.null.format"="") 
LOCATION 's3://path' ;
```

The file contains some missing values for the 'value' field (double type). It looks like this:

```
name,value,group    
name1,0.5,a
name2,0.2,a
name3,,a
name4,0.11,b
```

After creating it, when I try to run some queries (like a simple "select * from table"), Athena gives this error:

```
HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing column '1': empty String
```

As you can see from the create external table query, I tried to add 'serialization.null.format'='' but it doesn't seem to be working. The only solution I found was to define the column 'value' as a string, but it's obviously not the ideal one (especially if you have many columns like this).

Do you have any idea of how to resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: this is a `OpenCSVSerDe` limitation for non - `STRING` data types per the [`documentation`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html), can you try using `LazySimpleSerDe`?

Comment: it does work thanks! I wanted to use OpenCSVSerde to easily handle some double quoted values I have... But if there's this limitation, I guess I have to choose the lesser evil :)

Answer (score 2):

As Vamsi Prabhala mentions OpenCSVSerde simply does not support this, from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html):

> The parser does not recognize empty or null values in columns defined as a numeric data type, leaving them as the default data type of STRING. The workaround is to declare the column as STRING and then CAST it in a SELECT query or view.

So if you do want to stick with OpenCSVSerde, create the table as you did (`"serialization.null.format"=""` does not work):

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table`(
    name string,
    value double,
    group string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "separatorChar" = ",",
    "escapeChar" = "\\",
    "skip.header.line.count"="1") 
LOCATION 's3://path';
```

Then create a view as:

```sql
CREATE VIEW "typed_table" AS
SELECT
"name",
CAST(
    "value" CASE
        "value"
        WHEN '' THEN NULL
        ELSE "value"
    END AS DOUBLE
),
"group"
FROM "table";
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to watch out for here.

1. Whilst creating a table in Athena (eg from a CSV), you need to ensure that the table headers are not appearing.  If you notice the row 1 has the table headers, this may well be the reason why the HIVE_BAD_DATA error is appearing.
   You can ignore headers by simply by adding the table property

   TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1")

Eg.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table`(name string, value double, group string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",", "escapeChar" = "\\","skip.header.line.count"="1",  "serialization.null.format"="") 
LOCATION 's3://path' 
TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Alternately, if the table is already created, you can alter the table using

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1)
```

2. Whilst Querying the table, you might have to parse the string into the desired data_type.  You could do so by using cast or even date_parse
   Eg.

   SELECT * FROM table_name order by date_parse(field,'%d/%m/%Y') desc limit 100;