# HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '' for field 12: Cannot convert value of type String to a REAL value

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena

## Hello all !

[The query in Athena console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak8Js.png)
[The response error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el6xU.png)

```
 HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '' for field 12: Cannot convert value of type String to a REAL value
```

I try to create a Table queryable in Athena with a glue crawler where I specify each column's data type. My input is a CSV file where there are some empty fields.

[Crawler description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1BnJ.png)
[Crawler description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAekE.png)

The crawler finds each column and assigns the correct column name but when reading the values I have a parsing error.

I'm wondering if the problem could come from the crawler trying to read empty values as the wrong type.

[Error come from col data looking like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhvyV.png)
[Corresponding table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iktTi.png)

I tried unsuccessfully to change the serialization like in:

- [AWS Athena: "HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing column 'X' : empty String"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910540/aws-athena-hive-bad-data-error-parsing-column-x-empty-string)
- [Specify a SerDe serialization lib with AWS Glue Crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498330/specify-a-serde-serialization-lib-with-aws-glue-crawler)

Is there a parameter or a workaround to solve this issue?